# Kubernetes SharedInformer usage and definition

Tags: java, kubernetes, java-8, java-client

I have been trying to watch some resources in my K8s cluster and after reading some blogs about watch vs informers, i've decided to go with Informers.

I came across this example of how to use one: https://github.com/Netflix-Skunkworks/kubernetes-client-java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/examples/InformerExample.java

In the example, I see that the SharedIndexInformer is defined as such:

```
        factory.sharedIndexInformerFor(
            (CallGeneratorParams params) -> {
              return coreV1Api.listNodeCall(
                  null,
                  null,
                  null,
                  null,
                  null,
                  params.resourceVersion,
                  params.timeoutSeconds,
                  params.watch,
                  null,
                  null);
            },
            V1Node.class,
            V1NodeList.class);
```

Based on my understanding of how lambdas are written, this basically says that we're creating a `sharedIndexInformer` from the factory by passing it a param Call (returned by coreV1Api.listNodeCall).

The Call object is created by this dynamic method which takes in a `CallGeneratorParams` argument.

I do not seem to understand how and where this argument is passed in from in the case of a SharedInformerFactory. It's very evident that some fields within the `params` variable is being used in building the `listNodeCall` but where and how is this object constructed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's a ride down a rabbit hole.

> I suggest to keep the diagrams [from the official docs](https://github.com/huweihuang/kubernetes-notes/blob/master/code-analysis/kube-controller-manager/sharedIndexInformer.md) open in separate tab/window in order to appreciate the whole picture better.

In order to understand this, you would have to look at the implementation of the `SharedInformerFactory`, especially the [sharedIndexInformerFor](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/332c3a43bbd96b6814947f1f8543453b824ca253/util/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/informer/SharedInformerFactory.java#L115) call.

Notice how the lambda is just passed further down to construct a new [ListWatcher](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/332c3a43bbd96b6814947f1f8543453b824ca253/util/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/informer/ListerWatcher.java) instance [(method at line 194)](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/332c3a43bbd96b6814947f1f8543453b824ca253/util/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/informer/SharedInformerFactory.java#L194), which is then passed into a new [DefaultSharedIndexInformer](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/332c3a43bbd96b6814947f1f8543453b824ca253/util/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/informer/impl/DefaultSharedIndexInformer.java) instance [(statement at line 144)](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/332c3a43bbd96b6814947f1f8543453b824ca253/util/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/informer/SharedInformerFactory.java#L144).

So now we have an instance of a `SharedIndexInformer` that passes the `ListerWatcher` yet further down to its [Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/332c3a43bbd96b6814947f1f8543453b824ca253/util/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/informer/cache/Controller.java) [(constructor line 99)](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/332c3a43bbd96b6814947f1f8543453b824ca253/util/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/informer/impl/DefaultSharedIndexInformer.java#L99). Now the `Controller` is started when the `Informer` itself runs (see the `run()` method).

To make it even more complex, the `Controller` uses a `Reflector` for .. stuff. A `Reflector` according to the [reflector.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/353f0a5eabe4bd8d31bb67275ee4beeb4655be3f/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/reflector.go)

> Reflector watches a specified resource and causes all changes to be reflected in the given store.

So its job is to call `list` and `watch` until it is told to stop. So when the `Controller` starts, it also schedules its `Reflector` to [run periodically](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/332c3a43bbd96b6814947f1f8543453b824ca253/util/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/informer/cache/Controller.java#L116)

At last. When the `Reflector` runs, it calls the `list` method, which  .. *drum roll* .. [executes the lambda](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/332c3a43bbd96b6814947f1f8543453b824ca253/util/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/informer/SharedInformerFactory.java#L205) you were asking about. And the `param` variable in the lambda is .. *another drum roll* .. [created in the Reflector here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/332c3a43bbd96b6814947f1f8543453b824ca253/util/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/informer/cache/ReflectorRunnable.java#L89)

Pretty neat, wouldn't you say?

Let me know, if you need further help/clarification.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of functional style where a piece of code is declared/passed at one place but it's execution happens somewhere else. Easily a debugging nightmare.

> I do not seem to understand how and where this argument is passed in
> from in the case of a SharedInformerFactory. It's very evident that
> some fields within the params variable is being used in building the
> listNodeCall but where and how is this object constructed ?

In an IDE (Eclipse) - I simply tried finding where the public constructor of CallGeneratorParams is being called and it directly points me to ReflectorRunnable run method which in-turn is being called from the Controller. From there on you can follow the rabbit-hole ( as very well put by @isika)

```
ReflectorRunnable
```

[image: ReflectorRunnable]

```
Controller
```

[image]

`SharedInformerFactory` - the actual code which takes these params and does the work is below. However it's just place of definition - the time of execution is when the `ReflectorRunner` `run` method executes ( in the first image).

[image]